# C# Entity Framework: Keyword not supported: 'port'

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework

Hello I have more than one project connecting to a certain DB that is CodeFirst Entity Framework.

All Projects are able to connect successfully except for one stubborn one.

The error I am getting is: `Keyword not supported: 'port'`

I have looked through countless stackoverflow questions, mysql forums, entity framework forums etc. including:

[MappingException Edm.String not compatible with SqlServer.varbinary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697423/mappingexception-edm-string-not-compatable-with-sqlserver-varbinary)

[Keyword not supported in MySQL's connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333098/keyword-not-supported-in-mysqls-connection-string)

[Keyword not supported: 'metadata' + MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794616/keyword-not-supported-metadata-mysql)

My connection string looks like:
`server=myservername;port=3306;uid=myaccount;database=mydb;pwd=mypwd123`

My db.cs file looks like:

```
public partial class MyDB : DbContext
{
    public MyDB ()
        : base("server=myservername;port=3306;uid=myaccount;database=mydb;pwd=mypwd123")
    {
        Logger.Trace("test123");
    }

    public virtual DbSet<MyItem> MyItems { 
get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyItem>()
            .Property(e => e.Content)
            .IsUnicode(false);
    }
}
```

When I remove the `port:3306` from the connection string I get this:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.MappingException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(8,12) : error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.DateTime[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,Precision=]' of member 'Time' in type 'something.Model.MyItem' is not compatible with 'SqlServer.timestamp[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,MaxLength=8,FixedLength=True,StoreGeneratedPattern=Identity]' of member 'time' in type 'CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.MyItem'.
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.Init(EdmItemCollection edmCollection, StoreItemCollection storeCollection, IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IList`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection..ctor(EdmItemCollection edmCollection, StoreItemCollection storeCollection, IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.DbDatabaseMappingExtensions.ToStorageMappingItemCollection(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, EdmItemCollection itemCollection, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.DbDatabaseMappingExtensions.ToMetadataWorkspace(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.CodeFirstCachedMetadataWorkspace..ctor(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbCompiledModel..ctor(DbModel model)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
   at MyFunction(Int32 userId, String id, String type, String contentJsonString) in
```

I am using MySql Connector and not Sql Server...

I am completely stumped by this as well as the rest of my team.

Edit:
Here is my Web.Config

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
      </configSections>
      <appSettings file="config-sources\app-settings.config"/>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2">
          <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
          </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
      </system.web>
      <connectionStrings configSource="config-sources\ef-connection-strings.config"/>
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="C5687FC88969C44D" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.8.3.0" newVersion="6.8.3.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0"/>
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Autofac" publicKeyToken="17863af14b0044da" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.0.0" newVersion="3.3.0.0"/>
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.29.0" newVersion="4.2.29.0"/>
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
      <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
        <providers>
          <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices,          MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
      </entityFramework>
      <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
          <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
          <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="POST,HEAD,GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        </handlers>
        <security>
          <requestFiltering>
            <verbs>
              <add verb="POST" allowed="true"/>
            </verbs>
          </requestFiltering>
        </security>
        <defaultDocument>
          <files>
            <add value="webhook.ashx"/>
          </files>
        </defaultDocument>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Your port number is not the issue. You can't specify it like that but you shouldn't have to anyways unless you changed the Mysql default port.

Comment: Maybe this is the same issue you are having => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186044/sql-time-type-in-entity-framework-code-first

Comment: Can you post the relevant portion of the config file? The `port` exception indicates EF is trying to connect to Sql Server.

Comment: @NormTheThird, I looked into that and even after changing my DateTime to TimeSpan I still get this same error.
What is really weird is that the error is talking about SqlServer which I am not using nor do I want to use!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The argument of the used base `DbContext` [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.) is called `nameOrConnectionString`. Hence it supports a name of a connection string from the configuration file, or like in your case an actual connection string.

The problem with the latter is that it doesn't allow specifying the **provider name**, as with the former - coming from the configuration; in which case EF uses the one specified in the `defaultConnectionFactory` configuration element, which in your case is `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory`.

In other words - **Sql Server**; hence the `port` not supported exception.

There are several ways to fix the issue:

1. Change the `defaultConnectionFactory` configuration

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, 
MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"></defaultConnectionFactory>
```

2. Use named configuration connection string and specify explicitly the provider:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyDB" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
     connectionString="server=myservername;port=3306;
     uid=myaccount;database=mydb;pwd=mypwd123" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and change the constructor to:

```
public MyDB()
{
    // ...
}
```

or if the name is different than your `DbContext` derived class name:

```
public MyDB() : base(connection_string_name)
{
    // ...
}
```

3. Use [`DbConfigurationTypeAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbconfigurationtypeattribute(v=vs.113).aspx):

```
public class MyDB : DbContext 
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I ended up using option (A) although I wanted to use option (C)

I couldn't get an import of `MySql.Data.Entity` from anywhere...
Might have to update my MySqlConnector version for this

Comment: Where should I put (A) solution? In csproj?

Comment: @HaikalNashuha (A) is for App.config (or Web.config) file

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem whilst developing a Web Application on Core 2. I had to change the default database connection used from SqlServer to MySql in the Startup.cs file where the application is configured.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The error similar to the one listed above comes while working with ASP.net core and Database. The default database Provider with the ASP.net core is the SQL Server but, in case you are using a different provider for example, PostgreSQL and didn't correctly write or configure the DBContext code in the startup.cs

For example - Following code is written with an intent to connect to PostgresSQL then it will result in error **ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'port'.**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddMvc();
   var connection = @"Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=NewDB;User Id=xxxxx;Password=cr@aaaa;";
   services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

    // ...

}
```

And the reasons is user is trying to connect to PostgreSQL but did change the default Option UseSQLServer after configuring the PostgreSQL string.

To fix the issue change the option

---

> options.UseSqlServer(connection)) -> options.UseNpgsql(connection))

---

Answer (score 2):

I definitively solved the problem using the MySql Connector 8.0.x and following instructions on this link: https://davidsekar.com/asp-net/mysql-error-the-provider-did-not-return-a-providermanifesttoken.

in details:

1. Install MySql.Data.EntityFramework. Do not install Install MySql.Data.Entity!
2. Configure web.config / app.config in this way:

   2.1. Change the `<entityFramework>` tag to `<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.EntityFramework.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.EntityFramework">`

   2.2. Add/change the provider. It has to be: `<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework" />`

   2.3. Connection string now can be `server=myservername;port=3306;uid=myaccount;database=mydb;pwd=mypwd123`
3. Open your DbContext's configuration class (if presente) and place the following code in it's constructor:

   `SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient" new MySql.Data.EntityFramework.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, connection string with explicit port has to be delimited by `,`.

E.g.: `Data Source=123.45.123.45,1433;...`

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes it's the simplest thing. Mine was a copy-paste error when I missed the "Server=" at the beginning of the connection string.