# Entity framework works in console program but not in azure function

Tags: .net, entity-framework, azure-functions, npgsql

I am trying to build a solution architecture where I reference a .net project which contains all the code I need for an entity framework ORM which interfaces to a postgres database using the Npgsql provider.

Referencing such a project and making a query works in a console application but not in an azure function project.

[Here is a link to a solution](https://bitbucket.org/DCDprivate/ef-azf-ca/src) containing everything you need to reproduce this error. in `ConsoleApp1`, a reference to `eftest` is used and will run to completion without error.

The project named `FunctionApp3` is the fail case. A Brand new azure function project targeting .net framework 4.71, referencing the `eftest` project and querying it. If you try the project, [you will get this error](https://pastebin.com/N6pZdYjY).

Of course, when you actually install the `Npgsql 4.0.2` package it so desperately craves, it [changes to this error.](https://pastebin.com/9vr07bSA)

I thought this was a problem with a binding redirect. so I added an app.config similar to the one existing in the console app. Turns out that [azure functions cant use app.config files](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/354), so I cant set a binding redirect or a `providerName` attribute, in the connection string. To the best of my knowledge, `keyword port not supported` is caused by not setting the providerName in the connection string.

[Here is a log of the full rebuild of the azure function project.](https://pastebin.com/S3C6HRzd)

Question: How do I get this entity framework project working with an azure function project?

Comment: I have no idea about azure apps, but I wonder how your EF specific app settings are handled in the FunctionApp3 project. I mean the following parts from ConsoleApp1 `app.config`: `configSections`, `entityFramework/providers`, `connectionStrings/.../providerName`. With my limited understanding it looks as if these things would be unknown to the FunctionApp3 project

Comment: Regarding how to set providername without app.config, [this example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-function-with-entity-framework/) looks like you can write the local.settings.json connection strings with a more specific structure than you currently do.

Comment: have you seen this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45217166/c-sharp-entity-framework-keyword-not-supported-port?

Comment: No I haven't seen that project. thanks man I will have a read tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@grek40 provided the solution for the second bug by placing `ProviderName` as a property in the settings.json.

**updated settings.json**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
        "AzureWebJobsDashboard": ""

    },
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": {
            "ConnectionString": "Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=ef-azf-ca-testdatabase;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres;Pooling=true;Max Auto Prepare=10;Auto Prepare Min Usages=1;"
            "ProviderName":  "Npgsql"
        }
    }
}
```

As for the first problem, I have no ide awhy I cant use Npgsql version 4.0.3 but it doesnt matter since I can just use 4.0.2. Help us Roji, you are our only hope.