# Using port in sql connection string in C# Entity Framework: Keyword not supported: 'port'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-code

I've been working to set up Entity Framework using VS code, using this tutorial: 
https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/walkthroughs/aspnetcore-application 
however, when executing the migration- I encountered this specific error: Keyword not supported: 'port'
 The best reference I've found thus far to help out is this stackoverflow, however, due to the setup I've been following thus far, none of the solutions seem to work 
[C# Entity Framework: Keyword not supported: 'port'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45217166/c-sharp-entity-framework-keyword-not-supported-port)
 This is the code that seems to be causing me trouble:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
namespace EFPrac
{
    
    public class EFCoreWebDemoContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {            
            string connectionString = "server=localhost;port=3306;database=EFpractice;uid=root,Pwd=****";
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        }
    }
}
```

I've been stuck on this for a while, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com) is a great site for connection string question

**Using a non-standard port**

If your SQL Server listens on a non-default port you can specify that using the servername,xxxx syntax (note the comma, it's not a colon).

```
Server=myServerName,myPortNumber;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Also, try this way:

```
string connectionString="server=localhost,3306;database=EFpractice;uid=root,Pwd=****"
```

Comment: That's actually the site I used to create my connection string! I attempted your fix and a similar error continued: this time throwing: Internal connection fatal error.

Comment: Edit: tried the non-default port solution and  A connection was successfully established with the server, thanks for your help! I at least have a foothold to start debugging the new errors now!